# Using pug for self-contained (micro) widgets

Tags: css, pug

I've come to rely on pug 3 for a web project using Node.js 13 and Express 4.17 (using Parcel as the bundler).

I am playing with using Pug templates (using mixins) to develop reusable (mini) widgets to visualise content across a number of web pages. My goal is that these widgets are self-contained, in that they are containing some (default) styling CSS:

**widget.pug**

```
mixin widget(message)
    //- CSS
    style(type="text/css").
        .widget {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    //- Template
    .widget
        != message
```

I used this approach to self-contain widgets that are intended to be embedded in external web-pages in an iframe (separate browsing context, its own CSS etc.

In then started to look into applying this to my own pages. However, as you will no doubt see, there is a flaw with this approach in that it duplicates the styes as many times as I re-use the same widget on the same page. Not good.

Is there a way I can tell pug to include the style only once, and hoist it to the top-level of the scope when I compile the embedding template(s)?

I am using template inheritance (`extend _base`) and inclusion (`include widget.pug`), where the base template has a script block:

**base.pug**

```
block styles
```

**template.pug**

```
extends base

include widget.pug

block append styles
    style(type="text/css").
        .bar {
            color: red;
        }

    .bar
        +widget("Hello")
        +widget("world")
```

In this example, the styles block in the rendered HTML page would include duplicated CSS, which is undesirable.

This works fine for template inheritance, but I haven't found a way (is there any?) for the included widget to 'send' only one copy of the widget's CSS to the styles section defined in base.pug?

Cheers,
Michel

Comment: This isn't possible through Pug alone. Writing the CSS in CSS files would allow you to only include it once. You should also check out [Web Components & Custom Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) for another approach to reusable, self-contained "widgets".

Comment: Ah, pity. Thanks for the comment and resources; it triggered me to tackle another annoyance I have in the code elsewhere to replace with an elegant solution :-)